# Difference between signal and Call in sequence Diagram

Tags: uml, signals, enterprise-architect, sequence-diagram

In Enterprise Architect I want to model a Qt signal in a sequence diagram.

I use an asynchronous call of type signal.

When adding the message I can see that the asynchronous signal can be Call or Signal.

I'd like to know what's the difference between A signal and a call in a sequence diagram.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A call is an operation that waits for the return of the called object. In contrast a signal is just placed and no return is expected. Practically a signal is often realized with a semaphore.